# How to filter a JSON tree according to an attribute inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, underscore.js

I have to re-post this questions with more details again:

I got a JSON tree `array`.

The structure of JSON tree looks like this:

```
{
"app": {

    "categories": {

        "cat_222": {
            "id": "555",
            "deals": [{
                "id": "73",
                "retailer": "JeansWest"

            }, {
                "id": "8630",
                "retailer": "Adidas"

            }, {
                "id": "11912",
                "retailer": "Adidas"

            }]
        },

        "cat_342": {
            "id": "232",
            "deals": [{
                "id": "5698",
                "retailer": "KFC"
            }, {
                "id": "5701",
                "retailer": "KFC"
            }, {
                "id": "5699",
                "retailer": "MC"

            }]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

now, I'd like to filter this JSON tree with `var pattern="KF"`,

return all with `retailer` name contains `KF` with it's id.

======================update===========================

Just check my other question. It got solved.
[filter multi-dimension JSON arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18517004/765498)

Comment: Please post example of data, and your code so far.

Comment: I assume you already parsed the JSON. If yes then `array` contains a normal JS array. The question doesn't seem to have anything to do with JSON. Also, underscore.js has documentation, so why don't you look at it? http://underscorejs.org/#filter.

Comment: Use lodash rather than underscore. It is much much faster. In their benchmarks, it's like 240% faster than underscore's method on Chrome. The function and the arguments will be the same.

Comment: sorry guys, I edited my question again.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use [**_.filter**](http://underscorejs.org/#filter):

```
var filteredArray = _.filter(arrayOfStrings, function(str) { 
  return str.indexOf(data) !== -1; });
```

... or [**jQuery.grep**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/):

```
var filteredArray = $.grep(arrayOfStrings, function(str) { 
  return str.indexOf(data) !== -1; });
```

As you see, the approaches are quite similar - and, in fact, both use [**Array.filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), if it's available in the host environment.

Also note that the original array is not affected here. If you want otherwise, just assign the result of filtering to the same variable (i.e., `arrayOfStrings` in this example).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) if you need to support IE < 9