# filter multi-dimension JSON arrays

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

Here is the JSON details:

```
var array={
    "app": {
        "categories": {
            "cat_222": {
                "id": "555",
                "deals": [{
                    "id": "73",
                    "shop": "JeansWest"
                },
                {
                    "id": "8630",
                    "shop": "Adidas"

                },
                {
                    "id": "11912",
                    "shop": "Adidas"
                }]
            },
            "cat_342": {
                "id": "232",
                "deals": [{
                    "id": "5698",
                    "shop": "KFC"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5701",
                    "shop": "KFC"
                },
                {
                    "id": "5699",
                    "shop": "MC"
                }]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to filter the array to have `shop` which contain `da` pattern.

```
var filted = _.filter(array.app.categories,function(item) {
    return _.any(item.deals,function(c) {
        return c.shop.indexOf('da') != -1;
    });
});
```

=========UPDATE=============================================================

Just figured out, this code works. But it returns something like this:

```
[{
"id": "555",
"deals": [{
    "id": "73",
    "shop": "JeansWest"
}, {
    "id": "8630",
    "shop": "Adidas"
}, {
    "id": "11912",
    "shop": "Adidas"
}]
}]
```

ideally, I'd like to get something like this:

```
[{
"id": "555",
"deals": [{

    "id": "8630",
    "shop": "Adidas"
}, {
    "id": "11912",
    "shop": "Adidas"
}]
}]
```

Comment: To start, you are missing a `});` at the end of your `var filted = . . .` statement, but that might have just been a copy-and-paste error . . .

Comment: Modified.....it's copy-and-paste error...

Comment: `array.categories` doesn't exist.  It should be `array.app.categories`.

Comment: added...It's modified from a huge json array, sorry about the confustion... it still doesn't work

Comment: How does this "not work"?  What does it return?  What should it return?

Comment: P.S. Your `array` is actually an object, not an array.

Comment: it returns null.... supposed to return shop which contain da inside it.....

Comment: It seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/kWCvf/ (check the console).

Comment: Hi Rocket, I just updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
var filted = _.reduce(array.app.categories, function (memo, item) {
    var result = _.filter(item.deals, function (c) {
        return c.shop.indexOf('da') != -1;
    });

    if (result.length > 0) {
        var newResult = {};
        newResult.deals = result;
        newResult.id = item.id;
        memo = _.union(memo, newResult);
    }

    return memo;
}, []);
```